# Drupal twig template if mobile

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-templates

Ok, I am trying to develop drupal template and I need to tell you that I did not really understand how to use the If mobile.

```
{% if is_mobile() %}
{{ page.content }}
{% endif %}
```

I thought that this was working but I have errors.

i have also tried this

```
{% if is_mobile() %}
{% include '@header.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}
```

but is not working... so what I need to do?

Comment: "*but I have errors*" - So what errors do you have? [ask]  - Furthermore why don't you just use mediaqueries?

Comment: Blank page with error write on the top thar say "your website encoiluntred unexpected error" .

Comment: Please [enable the debug mode](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates) or check the actual error logs so you can provide the correct error

Comment: "The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later."    i don't have anything else on the screen even with debugger on

Comment: Without the real error it won't be possible to help you

Comment: I understand... I can tell you that in development mode, it is written as error 500.... if I remove this part everything is ok. i don't know why is so complicated now to develop templates. I was doing pretty good templates with Drupal 7 now... where the hell is the error code? Why the documentation is so terrible? The only that I can do is to put the file page.html.twig here

Comment: Are you using mobile_detect module or mobile_detect_twig_extensions module. Use mobile_detect now.

Comment: you may also check the 'logging and errors' section, under configuration->development to improve the error messages with more detailed information.

Comment: Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unknown "is_mobile" function. in Twig\ExpressionParser->getFunctionNodeClass() (line 2 of themes\djtotygee\templates\page.html.twig).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem.

The problem was that mobile_detect module was not installed properly for some reason.

Sorry to everybody